# Protect audio from being downloaded from S3 storage

Tags: audio, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js

There is a database of audio files that will be stored in the S3 storage. The site should allow users to play the files, but not to download them. What can I do so that the file can't be downloaded just by getting a link to it from inspecting the elements or using F12 developer tools?

The backend is written with Django REST API, the frontend with Nuxt.
I would be grateful for help in the direction of thought.

Right now, some advanced users can get a link directly to the audio file and download it, although only the playback functionality of the site is shown. This is possible by using inspect(F12) and further tracking the change of content on the page when you click on the "play" button.

Comment: You will need some DRM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) and also works with something that likely fetches "blocks" from (several) S3 buckets, making it hard/close to impossible to fetch it with a single item.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That could be an answer. (I'd be willing to upvote it at least, I'm admittedly not particularly knowledgeable about this topic, so it's informative for me too).